# How to solve the Index warning on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have introduced a new model to our Datastore a few days ago. Surprisingly I still get Index warnings

```
W 2014-02-09 03:38:28.480
suspended generator run_to_queue(query.py:938) raised NeedIndexError(no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: FeelTrackerRecord
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: timestamp)

W 2014-02-09 03:38:28.480
suspended generator helper(context.py:814) raised NeedIndexError(no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: FeelTrackerRecord
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: timestamp)
```

even though the index is served under `DataStore Indexes`

[image]

```
indexes:

# AUTOGENERATED

# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the dev_appserver
# detects that a new type of query is run.  If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the above marker line (the line
# saying "# AUTOGENERATED").  If you want to manage some indexes
# manually, move them above the marker line.  The index.yaml file is
# automatically uploaded to the admin console when you next deploy
# your application using appcfg.py.


- kind: FeelTrackerRecord
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: record_date
  - name: timestamp
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: You should show the the code that threw the exception. Since the log only shows one property for the suggested index. Problably you have a query with ancestor and inequality filters for the timestamp property, for that you need a the index that app engine tells you to use.

Comment: You indexes as listed do not match the recommended index.  They must match exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned in a comment your indexes don't match the required.  The error says

```
raised NeedIndexError(no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: FeelTrackerRecord
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: timestamp)
```

However you the index you list is different

```
- kind: FeelTrackerRecord
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: record_date
  - name: timestamp
```

Do you see the difference ?

Just add the index as listed and update your indexes.

Comment: Still getting this error about everytime I start a new GAE project. I'm sure the index.yaml is correct; i just commit the one generated by local GoogleAppEngineLauncher, and it looks exactly like the suggested one in the error. It seems that this problem "fixes itself" after some time, but it's kinda unclear when that happens.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the problem.

Best way to solve this is to make sure the local `index.yaml` is empty (delete all the indices). Then simply run your GAE app on localhost and access your app as you would expect.
Http access is pretty straightforward over browser and if GET/POST over REST is required you can use `curl` from a terminal:

**GET:**

```
curl --user test@gmail.com:test123 http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/records/1391944029
```

**POST:**

```
curl --user test@gmail.com:test123  http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/records/1391944029 -d '{"records": [
        {
            "notes": "update", 
            "record_date": "2014-02-02", 
            "timestamp": 1391944929
        }
    ], "server_sync_timestamp": null}' -X POST -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

GAE is now updating the `index.yaml` automatically and add the correct indices in there.

After your deploying your app, you need to cleanup the old indices.
This is done through a terminal:

```
appcfg.py vacuum_indexes src
```

After login with credentials it will ask you about the old indices that are no longer in your `index.yaml` and if they should be deleted. Press y and continue.